# how to add a sharepointintegration connector to my powerapp

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have a customised form in my powerapps that reads from my sharepoint list.
Apparently it requires a SharepointIntegration connector to work. (as attached)

Please help:
[image]

Ive tried searching all over google and stack overflow but no answers

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:
[image]
[image]
[image]
For more information, please refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-sharepoint-online
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/add-manage-connections

Answer (score 0):

`SharePointIntegration` control/object is only available when you customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps.

**Documentation**:

1. [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)
2. [Understand SharePoint forms integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/sharepoint-form-integration)

---

You cannot add this object while creating a standalone canvas Power apps.

1. From canvas app you can use **Form** control with SharePoint data source and use `SubmitForm()` function to submit data to SharePoint list. **OR**
2. Use custom form created using any controls in canvas app and save data in SharePoint list using `Patch` function.

In above cases you don't need `SharePointIntegration` object in standalone canvas app to work with SharePoint data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of different things:

Add the connection to SharePoint, and add the datasource of the list to the form. Add an Edit Form to the screen.

If it doesn't add it by default:
Instead of trying to use the `SharePointIntegration` in the `Items` property, just do this: `Defaults('SharePoint list name')`

In your Submit button, ensure you have your `ResetForm(form1)` and `NewForm(form1)` and `RequestHide()` in your OnSelect after you do your `SubmitForm(form1)` or `Patch()` method, because you'll have to handle these all in that area, instead of being able to rely on the SharePoint Integration.